# Разница между zeroMQ и websocket

Tags: python, сокет, zeromq

Я пишу p2p программу на python, где ноды будут общаться между собой (блокчейн). Я решил писать на zeroMQ, но умные люди сказали писать на websocket, так как клиенту будет проще общаться с нодами через сайт и плюс разработчикам будет проще писать приложения под этот блокчейн. Можете подсказать?

Comment: zeromq это *библиотека* (concurrency framework), предоставляющая примитивы, позволяющие поверх  известных шаблонов объединять компоненты в [раcпределённом] приложении. websocket это *протокол*, встроенный [в основном] в браузеры, позволяющий javascript коду с сервером общаться. Это как сравнивать набор сделай сам (со сложными хорошо компонуемыми блоками) и описание относительно низкоуровневой детальки, используемой для специфического типа соединения.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо, что объяснил на пальцах, теперь более менее понятно. правильно ли что я выбрал для общения между компьютеров в распределенной системе именно zeroMQ?

Comment: не имею представления